# passing parameter to ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult always default

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass parameter for ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult() but it's always null (getParcelableExtra), or default (getIntExtra). I don't understand what I do wrong.

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                    Log.v(Consts.TAG, "result : " + result.getData().getIntExtra("code", -1));
                }
            });
    imgButtonGal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Integer code = 111;
        intent.putExtra("code", code);
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    });
```

I always get :

```
result : -1
```

(Code is just an example, don't focus on intent type please)

Comment: You cannot attach extras to an outbound `Intent` and get those passed back to you in a result `Intent`, unless you specifically wrote the activity responding to the `Intent` to do that. You did not write the `ACTION_PICK` activity, most likely.

Comment: Ok, thanks @CommonsWare, so, how can I do to pass a argument please ?

Comment: That is not an option, sorry. If you want to remember the value of `code`, hold onto it in your app in some variable (ideally, one saved to a suitable saved instance state `Bundle`, in case Android terminates your app process while the user is in the app that you're starting).